# How to disable text insertion in emacs when i particular minor mode?

Tags: emacs

How to make emacs not insert text when character keys are pressed?
For instance, I have a minor mode and when I enter it I want to disable text insertion.

```lisp
(defun marko-enter-edit-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (set-cursor-color "#ffffff")
  (marko-nav-mode -1))
```

Comment: Add this: `(setq buffer-read-only t)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable (or re-enable) text insertion, set [`buffer-read-only`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Read-Only-Buffers.html).

If you want to associate this action with a minor mode, you might prefer to use the mode hook rather than a separate function.

Recommended reading:

- [`define-minor-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Minor-Modes.html)
- [`special-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Major-Modes.html) (if your mode is in fact *major* and read-only, you should inherit from this)